# python default dictionary equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, python, dictionary

What is equivalent to Python dictionary like this but in C#

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(list) # default dictionary to store graph
```

I thought it is simple dictionary but then I saw if statement like this and got confused; V is integer of nodes in a graph:

```
  for i in range(V):
        if len(graph[i]) %2 != 0 :
            u = i
            break
```

What this if statement is checking?

Comment: A dictionary in c# is a Collection of KeyPariValue<,>. The key is a hash table to make lookup quicker.  In python it looks like it is not really a dictionary.  It looks like they are using a List<> where the even indexes are the key and the odd indexes are the values.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing equivalent per se.
This is the closest you can get.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> graph = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

The difference is that in Python you will get a default empty list for free for every key.
In c# you will have to new up a new list if the key if not present.